# Even after lowering the ios version in tiapp.xml , still throwing an error

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I'm trying to check my application on my device but I have `iOS 5.1.1`. So I've set  as 5.0 in tiapp.xml.

It is still throwing an error when I try to run it.

**Error:**

```
The device is running `iOS 5.1.1`, however the app's the minimum iOS version is set to 6.0
In order to install this app on this device, lower the <min-ios-ver> to 5.1 in the **tiapp.xml**:

[ERROR] :  This app does not support the device "XXXXXX’s iPhone"
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <ios>
        <min-ios-ver>5.0</min-ios-ver>
    </ios>
</ti:app>
```

I have already added the "min-ios-version" tag still throwing the same error.

**tiapp.xml**:

```
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">

    <id>com.XXXXXXXX</id>
    <name>Taxi</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <publisher>XXXXXX</publisher>
    <url>http://</url>
    <description>not specified</description>
    <copyright>2014 by XXXXX</copyright>
    <icon>appicon.png</icon>
    <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
    <navbar-hidden>false</navbar-hidden>
    <analytics>true</analytics>
    <guid>e7914e57-5b00-4ade-8254-1044c0c65b67</guid>
    <property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
    <ios>
        <min-ios-ver>5.0</min-ios-ver>
        <plist>
            <dict>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                </array>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
                </array>
                <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
                <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
            </dict>
        </plist>
    </ios>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
    <mobileweb>
        <precache/>
        <splash>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <inline-css-images>true</inline-css-images>
        </splash>
        <theme>default</theme>
    </mobileweb>
    <modules>
        <module platform="commonjs">ti.cloud</module>
        <module platform="iphone">ti.map</module>
        <module platform="android">ti.map</module>
    </modules>
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="android">true</target>
        <target device="blackberry">false</target>
        <target device="ipad">true</target>
        <target device="iphone">true</target>
        <target device="mobileweb">true</target>
        <target device="tizen">false</target>
    </deployment-targets>
    <sdk-version>3.2.1.GA</sdk-version>

    </ti:app>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing cleaning project before building it?

Comment: I did try cleaning that didn`t help

Answer (score 0):

try to set min version in xcode before creating ipa